# The use of the adjective "slippery in context

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to say *it is slippery* meaning that roads, sidewalks and what not is covered in ice. For example:

> You had better put on boots with good traction as **it is slippery** today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Cambridge, *"If something is slippery, it is wet or smooth so that it slides easily or causes something to slide."*

> The road was wet and slippery yesterday. But with the sun shining bright, it won't be as slippery today.

I think with proper context, it would sound natural. This is common in speech where the listener knows what you are talking about. I would say that if this is something you are writing, it will serve you well to identify what "it" is (i.e., roads, sidewalks, bicycle lanes, etc.).

Here are other examples from google books:

> - Peter first notes the slippery conditions – "y'see there's still snow there it'll just be a bit more slippery today"
> - ... said Anita as they strolled past the Tilapia ponds and faced the steep climb up to the path that ran a little way from the fast moving asphalt road, "It won't be as slippery today."

Alternatively, you could say *"... as it is slippery **outside**"* or the full version *"... as the roads and sidewalks are slippery today"*.